# input allows to write 1 symbol only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, focus

there are radio buttons on the page.
When the radio buttons are clicked - should be some elemnts shown or hidden.

But when the "search" is selected - it allows to write 1 symbol only and become invisible.

Plase, see the code example here : https://codesandbox.io/embed/keen-hodgkin-4f4jy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please add what your actual question is? What's the error you are getting and where exactly do you need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is this

```
 <div
    className="buttons-wrapper"
    onChange={e => this.handleButtonsChange(e)}
 >
```

Try to log value of `this.state.value` in render, then, while you type something in input, you will see input value is stored in `this.state.value`. Hence this check fails afterwards: `this.props.change === "3"`, hiding input.
That top level `onChange` is causing you trouble. Move that change handler to the inputs:

```
  <input onChange={e => this.handleButtonsChange(e)} type="radio" id="random" name="btn" value={1} />
```

Comment: An alternative would be to keep the event delegation (since that's good) but only apply it when needed. `<div ... onChange={e => e.target.tagName === 'input' && e.target.name === 'btn' ? this.handleButtonsChange(e) : true}>`

Comment: Yes, great :) Thanks a lot.

I moved the handler to inputs and it works now